# No wired connection from router when waking up from suspend/reboot/reconnect

Tags: wireless, suspend, wired

So up until recently my 5 year old Linksys WRT54GL router was working fine, but for a few days now everytime I wake up Ubuntu from suspend I have no wired internet (wireless devices still have internet), and the only way to fix it is to turn off and turn on the router.

If I don't do that I can't even access administrator page at 192.168.1.1. It's the same if I disconnect ethernet cable and plug it in again to laptop, I won't have internet unless reboot router once again.

How can I fix it, because it was working perfectly before.

Comment: I have the same problem. Rebooting my machine also seems to work.

Comment: @caarlos0 Well I think for me it's opposite - if I reboot or wake up Ubuntu, then I need to restart router, otherwise no internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my `/etc/network/interfaces` and it was like this (I never changed anything before):

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

So I modified it:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And now it automatically connects when I reboot or plug the ethernet cable. Not sure why was this the solution because I never touched `interfaces` file.